# Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert (moralis tutorial)

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, migration

how are you guys?
i was watching this video tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y519kGkAQd8&list=RDCMUCgWS9Q3P5AxCWyQLT2kQhBw&t=235s
and when i execute this command

`truffle migrate --network development`

i recived this error:

`Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`

anyone here can help me?
CODE

Token.sol

```
pragma solidity 0.8.10;

import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Token is ERC721, Ownable {
    struct Pet {
        uint8 damage; //0-255
        uint8 magic;
        uint256 lastMeal;
        uint256 endurance; // 24 hours
    }
    uint256 nextId = 0;
    mapping(uint256 => Pet) private _tokenDetails;

    constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol)
        ERC721(name, symbol)
    {}

    function getTokenDetails(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (Pet memory) {
        return _tokenDetails[tokenId];
    }

    function mint(uint8 damage, uint8 magic, uint256 endurance) public onlyOwner {
        _safeMint(msg.sender, nextId);
        _tokenDetails[nextId] = Pet(damage, magic, block.timestamp, endurance);
        nextId++;
    }

    function feed(uint256 tokenId) public {
        Pet storage pet = _tokenDetails[nextId];
        require(pet.lastMeal + pet.endurance > block.timestamp);
        pet.lastMeal = block.timestamp;
    }

    function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) internal override {
        Pet storage pet = _tokenDetails[nextId];
        require(pet.lastMeal + pet.endurance > block.timestamp); //Pet still alive
    }
}
```

2_token_migration.js

```
const Token = artifacts.require("Token");

module.exports = async function (deployer) {
  await deployer.deploy(Token, "NFT Game", "NFTG");
  let tokenInstance = await Token.deployed();
  await tokenInstance.mint(100,200,100000); // Token id 0
  let pet = await tokenInstance.getTokenDetails(0);
  console.log(pet)
};
```

Error that has return

```bash
Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
    at module.exports (C:\Projetos\NFT\NFTGameMoralis\migrations\2_token_migration.js:6:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at Migration._deploy (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\Migration.js:75:1)
    at Migration._load (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\Migration.js:56:1)
    at Migration.run (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\Migration.js:217:1)
    at Object.runMigrations (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\index.js:150:1)
    at Object.runFrom (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\index.js:110:1)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\migrate\index.js:87:1)
    at runMigrations (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\commands\migrate.js:258:1)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\commands\migrate.js:223:1)
    at Command.run (C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\command.js:183:1)
Truffle v5.4.21 (core: 5.4.21)
Node v16.13.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first issue is here :

```
function mint(uint8 damage, uint8 magic, uint256 endurance) public onlyOwner {
    _safeMint(msg.sender, nextId);
    _tokenDetails[nextId] = Pet(damage, magic, block.timestamp, endurance);
    nextId++;
}
```

`_safeMint` will internally call `_beforeTokenTransfer`. Your implementation of `_beforeTokenTransfer` needs to access the Pet structure for a given tokenId, but those are only set after calling `_safeMint` in your code.

To fix this you need to reverse the call order :

```
function mint(uint8 damage, uint8 magic, uint256 endurance) public onlyOwner {
        _tokenDetails[nextId] = Pet(damage, magic, block.timestamp, endurance);
        _safeMint(msg.sender, nextId);
        nextId++;
    }
```

Additionally, I think you have an error in your `_beforeTokenTransfer` implementation :

```
function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) internal override {
        Pet storage pet = _tokenDetails[nextId];
        require(pet.lastMeal + pet.endurance > block.timestamp); //Pet still alive
    }
```

`_tokenDetails[nextId]` cannot be right. It will pass for your mint operation but will lead to unwanted behavior if you allow transfer of the NFT. The correct implementation should use the `tokenId` received as parameter. So like this :

```
function _beforeTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) internal override {
        Pet storage pet = _tokenDetails[tokenId];
        require(pet.lastMeal + pet.endurance > block.timestamp); //Pet still alive
    }
```

You would have figured quickly where the error is if you gave an error message to your require statement in `_beforeTokenTransfer`. Use them, as you see they can be very convenient.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i just change what you said to me, and works, 
i use nextId because i incremente ID, like
Pet "one" id = 0
pet "two" id = 1

Comment: Incrementing nextId is fine in mint. But you should use tokenId in _beforeTokenTransfer. Think about it that way, if I have the token with id 1 , but nextId is currently at 30, if I try to transfer my token (id 1) you will check against the data for nextId (which doesn't exist yet by definition) so I won't be able to transfer tokens as your require statement will always be false.